# How to refresh / reinitialize CefSharp

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp Offscreen in my wpf application to generate screenshot of website. It works well but I need to check if there is some certificate errors on page and it should be configurable while application is running.
I added checkbox: "Ignore certificate errors" to form. Then I implemented MyRequestHandler for ChrominiumWebBrowser `IRequestHandler`.

```
private class MyRequestHandler : IRequestHandler
        {
            public event EventHandler<LoadErrorEventArgs> CertificateError;

            public bool IgnoreCertErrors { get; set; }

            public bool OnBeforeBrowse(IWebBrowser browser, IRequest request, bool isRedirect, bool isMainFrame)
            {
                return false;
            }

            public bool OnCertificateError(IWebBrowser browser, CefErrorCode errorCode, string requestUrl)
            {
                if (IgnoreCertErrors)
                {
                    return true;
                }    
                var handler = CertificateError;
                if (handler != null)
                {
                    handler(browser, new LoadErrorEventArgs(requestUrl, errorCode, Resources.InvalidCert));
                }    
                return false;
            }

            public void OnPluginCrashed(IWebBrowser browser, string pluginPath)
            {
            }

            public CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser browser, IRequest request, bool isMainFrame)
            {
                return CefReturnValue.Continue;
            }

            public bool GetAuthCredentials(IWebBrowser browser, bool isProxy, string host, int port, string realm, string scheme, ref string username, ref string password)
            {
                return true;
            }

            public bool OnBeforePluginLoad(IWebBrowser browser, string url, string policyUrl, WebPluginInfo info)
            {
                return false;
            }

            public void OnRenderProcessTerminated(IWebBrowser browser, CefTerminationStatus status)
            {
            }
        }
```

**Browser Initialization**:

```
browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
browser.LoadError += BrowserLoadError;
requestHandler = new MyRequestHandler() { IgnoreCertErrors = ignoreCertErrors };
requestHandler.CertificateError += BrowserLoadError;
browser.RequestHandler = requestHandler;
```

If I start application with `IgnoreCertErrors = true` it works ok and certificate errors are ignored.

If I start with `IgnoreCertErrors = false` it also works ok and CertificateError is raised.

Problem is when I try to change `IgnoreCertErrors` when application is running. When I start app with false and then switch from false --> true it is ok, but when I try change it from true to false the `OnCertificateError` method is not raised so I have no chance to check my parameter.

Is there caching or something? Maybe whole my approach is wrong?
Is there any possibility to reinitialize CefSharp?

Better example:
Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="ceftest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Closed="Window_Closed">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Grid.Column="1" Click="Button_Click">Generate Screenshot</Button>
            <CheckBox Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked">Ignore cert errors</CheckBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code-behind**:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
        bool ignoreCertErrors = false;            
        string url = ""; // some page with invalid certificate

        public MainWindow()
        {
            Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (browser != null  && browser.IsBrowserInitialized)
            {
                browser.Dispose();
            }    
            browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
            browser.LoadError += BrowserLoadError;
            var requestHandler = new RequestHandler() { IgnoreCertErrors = ignoreCertErrors };
            requestHandler.CertificateError += BrowserLoadError;
            browser.RequestHandler = requestHandler;    
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            browser.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1000, 700);
            browser.NewScreenshot += ScreenshotGenerated;    
            browser.Load(url);
        }

        private void ScreenshotGenerated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // I get here screenshot from browser.ScreenshotAsync and put it into Image control
        }

        private void BrowserLoadError(object sender, LoadErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ErrorCode + " " + e.ErrorText);
        }

        private void CheckBox_Checked(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ignoreCertErrors = true;
        }

        private void CheckBox_Unchecked(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ignoreCertErrors = false;
        }

        private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Cef.Shutdown();
        }
    }

    class RequestHandler : IRequestHandler
    {
        public event EventHandler<LoadErrorEventArgs> CertificateError;

        public bool IgnoreCertErrors { get; set; }

        public bool GetAuthCredentials(IWebBrowser browser, bool isProxy, string host, int port, string realm, string scheme, ref string username, ref string password)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public bool OnBeforeBrowse(IWebBrowser browser, IRequest request, bool isRedirect, bool isMainFrame)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public bool OnBeforePluginLoad(IWebBrowser browser, string url, string policyUrl, WebPluginInfo info)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser browser, IRequest request, bool isMainFrame)
        {
            return CefReturnValue.Continue;
        }

        public bool OnCertificateError(IWebBrowser browser, CefErrorCode errorCode, string requestUrl)
        {
            if (IgnoreCertErrors)
            {
                return true;
            }

            var handler = CertificateError;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(browser, new LoadErrorEventArgs(requestUrl, errorCode, "certificate error"));
            }

            return false;
        }

        public void OnPluginCrashed(IWebBrowser browser, string pluginPath)
        {
        }

        public void OnRenderProcessTerminated(IWebBrowser browser, CefTerminationStatus status)
        {
        }
    }
```

CefSharp Offscreen version 41.0.1.0

Comment: If you try navigating to a different domain, then back to the domain with the invalid certificate is the handler raised again? I believe `CEF` will cache the response for the lifespan of the `Render Process`, so navigating to a different domain and back will spawn a different `Render Process`. That or you can create a new `ChromiumWebBrowser` instance.

Comment: I tried both. I create new ChrominiumWebBrowser every time I click "generate screenshot" and it does not work. However after over a dozen clicks it works and OnCertificateError is called.

Comment: Can you easily reproduce the problem by forking https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample?

Comment: I added better example to my post.

Comment: Everything looks ok. Without a fully working example it's hard to say much else. See http://magpcss.org/ceforum/ for general information about CEF, excellent resource.